# <select> design is not visible at first download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I use Rails 4 and bootstrap-select-rails gem.
When I download page with my form, I got this

[image: first download]

When I refresh page, I got this

[image]

If I turn off turbolinks,  design is ok, but site is very slow.
How to display the correct design at first download without disabling turbolinks?

UPD:
at application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap-select
```

at application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-select";
```

at view:

```
=select_tag "document_id",
  options_from_collection_for_select(@documents,'id', 'name'),
  class: "selectpicker", 
  "data-live-search".to_sym => "true"
```

Comment: Please post your related code.

Comment: Done. Post has been edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added data-no-turbolink attribute to link

```
<a href="page_with_form" data-no-turbolink="true">New</a>
```